# Rearrange characters in a string such that no two adjacent are same

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, priority-queue

Can someone explain me this line of code:

```
pq.push( Key { count[c-'a'], c} )
```

And how does the overloading operator work for this code?

Why is it that I am not able to change this particular line

```
bool operator <(const Key &k) const
```

to this particular `operator>`

```
bool operator >(const Key &k) const
```

Complete code is given below

```
    const int MAX_CHAR = 26;

struct Key
{
    int freq; 
    char ch;
     bool operator <(const Key &k) const
    {
        return freq < k.freq;
    }

};
void rearrangeString(string str)
{
    int n = str.length();
    int count[MAX_CHAR] = {0};
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        count[str[i]-'a']++;
        cout<<"count "<<str[i]-'a'<<" "<<count[str[i]-'a']<<" "<<endl;
    }
    priority_queue< Key > pq;
    for (char c = 'a' ; c <= 'z' ; c++)
        if (count[c-'a'])
            pq.push( Key { count[c-'a'], c} );

    cout<<endl<<pq.top().ch;
    str = "" ;

    Key prev {-1, '#'} ;
    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        Key k = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        str = str + k.ch;
        if (prev.freq > 0)
            pq.push(prev);
        (k.freq)--;
        prev = k;
    }
    if (n != str.length())
        cout << " Not valid String " << endl;

    else 
        cout << str << endl;
}
int main()
{
    string str = "bbbaa" ;
    rearrangeString(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Key { count[c-'a'], c}` constructs a `Key` object by initializing `freq` to `count[c-'a']` and `ch` to `c`. Then that object is passed as an argument to the `pq.push` call.

`operator >` doesn't work because you're the `Key` in a `std::priority_queue` whose default comparer uses `<`. To make it use `>` instead, declare `pq` like so:

```
std::priority_queue<Key, std::vector<Key>, std::greater<Key>> pq;
```